# What does the `listen` directive actually listen for in nginx?

Tags: nginx

The syntax of `listen` directive is known as the following.

```
server {
    listen ADDRESS:PORT;
}
```

But what the ADDRESS and PORT mean here?
ADDRESS of client IP address? or server IP address? or the requested IP address? So as the PORT part, who's port to listen for??

Suppose I have a situation like this
[image]

Would the correct arguments of the `listen` directive be this or not ?

```
listen 46.137.123.236:80;
```

And, in which case should I specify an IP address instead of `*:80`?

Comment: Your diagram is confusing. How does the request to `46.137.123.236` end up at `192.168.11.12`? In the vast majority of circumstances it is only necessary to specify the port, e.g. `listen 80;`

Comment: @Richard Smith I edited the image. Maybe there is a load balancer or reverse proxy server sits in between. I make the host IP different from request IP because I want to know if it should be the host IP(port) or requests IP(port).

Comment: If you must specify an IP address (which generally you should not), it is the IP address of a particular interface on the server (in this case 192.168.11.12)

Comment: @RichardSmith If you only want to listen for traffic through a specific Ip address due to security or other good reasons one should not exclude the Ip address, else Nginx will just listen on all network interfaces. If you always know that all traffic will be coming from through the public-ip address of the server, then why not just set `listen public-ip:80`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listen directive specifies the nginx server ip and port. Requests are routed to nginx which then distributes them to the upstream pool. Based on your diagram, the host running nginx is at `46.137.123.236` and the `192.168.11.12` address is the pool member upstream which nginx is routing the requests to.

The ip is the ip of the host that the nginx application is running on. As for the port, you choose your own port. You will have to make sure the port is open and not restricted under any firewall or being used by another program. While you can use any port of your choosing, it is common practice to use specific ports for certain types of applications. For instance an http server would generally use port 80 and internet browsers use this port by default. If you chose a different port and were using a browser you would explicitly specify your chosen port in the request. In your example, assuming that the request ip and port is where nginx is, then you are correct by specifying listen `46.137.123.236:80;` as the ip and port.

It is customary to use alternate ports when you forward https. For instance you could use 443 in such case. In a corporate environment, it is likely you will have only a few ports at your disposal and in such case there are standard ports for http and https.

Comment: If the ADDRESS is my host IP, why should I even specify it intentionally 
 however? I mean there's only one IP for my host, what's the reason there's an option allow me to specify an IP? I think it's implicit to be my host IP.

Comment: @yaquawa. Yes correct `*:80` would suffice in such case, as long as the this host is running the application (nginx).

Comment: "If the ADDRESS is my host IP, why should I even specify it intentionally however?" @yaquawa you can specify for example, `127.0.0.1:80` and nginx would only listen from requests originating internally, as opposed to accepting external requests on port 80.